# Assigning variable inside the EOF

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, sh

This part of the code works on Ubuntu 16.04 but when I try to run this code on CentOS 6.x the value of `server_url` were not assigned properly, the value becomes blank.

Here's my code:

```
server_url="http://local.host.net"

cat > /etc/cron.daily/update_rules.sh <<EOF
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /opt/rules
rm -f /opt/rules/rules.tmp

echo "[`date`] Updating rules ..."
wget $server_url -O /opt/rules/rules.tmp && \
    mv /opt/rules/mhn.rules.tmp /opt/rules/mhn.rules && \
    (/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl update ; /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart appserv ) && \
    echo "[`date`] Successfully updated the rules" && \
    exit 0

echo "[`date`] Failed to the rules"
exit 1
EOF
```

I'm getting this result, take note of line 6:

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p /opt/rules
rm -f /opt/rules/rules.tmp

echo "[Tue Aug 29 16:42:26 UTC 2017] Updating rules ..."
wget  -O /opt/rules/rules.tmp && \
    mv /opt/rules/mhn.rules.tmp /opt/rules/mhn.rules && \
    (/usr/local/bin/supervisorctl update ; /usr/local/bin/supervisorctl restart appserv ) && \
    echo "[`date`] Successfully updated the rules" && \
    exit 0

echo "[Tue Aug 29 16:42:26 UTC 2017] Failed to the rules"
exit 1
```

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Quoting the here-doc delimiter (e.g. `<<'EOF'`) or using a Unicode-lookalike instead of an ASCII backquote (say, `‘` or `‛`) could explain the failure to execute the `date` command, but neither appears to be the case. Regardless, you should use `$(date)` in place of backquotes.

Comment: I cannot explain the expansion of `$server_url` to the empty string instead of the assigned value at all.

Comment: @chepner My mistake. I've already edited the date. Thanks

Comment: What happens if you run the script with `bash -u`? (I'm stretching here, but I want to confirm that `server_url` is the actual name used for both the assignment and the expansion.)

Comment: Wait, let me check. I'll update you once done.